# Laravel 5.6 - Code In view - best practice

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am new to the Laravel framework and I am finding that on many of my views, I need to have similar code as seen below.  I am sure this is not best practice. Can someone advise me what would be the best practice approach on this?

```
<?php 
use App\Song;
use App\Music;
$songArtist = Song::find('5b0a6a779a892025b869f552')->Artists()->get();
?>

<div class="form-group row">
...

</div>
```

I could then use the $songArtist variable... Note, I am using MongoDB on the backend.

Comment: At first you should not put the logic into the views. Put the logics into the controllers instead.

Comment: You seem to be missing the controller's purpose.  $songArtist should be defined/retrieved in the controller and passed to the view as a part of the controller method's return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read on the MVC or Model-View-Controller architecture. There are many arguments as to whether Laravel is an MVC Framework or not, but in this case, let's assume that it uses the said architecture.

The way you pull the data/logic is normally handled by the model. The controller will be handling the way the data will be transported into the view (html). Lastly, the view will serve as the user-interface. This should make your code cleaner and organized.

A typical example would be like this:

Controller

```
use App\Song;
use App\Music;

function getArtist()
{
   $songArtist = Song::find('5b0a6a779a892025b869f552')->Artists()->get();
   return view('myhtml')->with('songArtist', $songArtist);
}
```

View

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <p> {{ $songArtist}} </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, in MVC, the model should handle the logic.  The controller is the transport layer (retrieving the data from the models and passing it to the views)

Comment: Thanks for a better definition! Will try to rephrase my answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.